# How to solve recursive call that causes stack overflow error in Android?

Tags: java, android, recursion, android-handler

I have a scheduled interval task in my Android application. Assume that it is a task of health check to a USB-connected device and it is running every 10 minutes. According to the class code below, the task is started by calling `start()` method.

```
//...

/**
 * Handler callback
 */
private Runnable handlerCallback = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        sendRequest();
        handler.postDelayed(handlerCallback, interval);
    }
};

/**
 * Start the repeated task
 */
public void start() {
    handlerCallback.run();
}

/**
 * Stop the task
 */
public void stop() {
    handler.removeCallbacks(handlerCallback);
}

/**
 * Send request
 */
public void sendRequest() {
    CmdRequestHealthCheck cmd = new CmdRequestHealthCheck();
    mAccessor.Write(cmd.get(), mWrite);
}

/**
 * Request Health Check
 */
protected final WriteCallback mWrite = new WriteCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onWrite(boolean bStatus, Exception oError) {
        if (bStatus) {
            // Success
            repeatCounter = Globals.HEALTH_CHECK_REPEAT;
            Toast.makeText(context, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            // Fail
            if (repeatCounter == 0) {
                // finally show error
                Toast.makeText(context, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                // if there is error message returned
                if (oError != null) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, oError.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } else {
                // Immediate Retry for xx times
                sendRequest();
                repeatCounter--;
            }
        }
    }
};
```

When a first request failed, the immediate second request will be sent without waiting for the next interval 10 minutes. The immediate next checks will be sent according to `repeatCounter`, for example, 2 times or 3 times. However, when the second `sendRequest()` is called in `onWrite()`, `threadid=1: stack overflow on call` is thrown. I guess it is a recursive problem.

`mWrite` is a callback to `mAccessor.Write()`;

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've spotted 2 possible issues:

1. decrement `repeatCounter` **before** calling `sendRequest` again.
2. the stop case should be - "`if (repeatCounter <= 0)`" not "`==`" to avoid possible issues where you decrement twice before getting to the point of checking the value at `repeatCounter`